# How do I enable drop-in calling on Alexa?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I've configured my Echo and the associated Alexa app for calling and can call registered users. However, though I've read about the drop-in calling feature, I don't see any way to enable it.  How do I enable and use drop-in?

Comment: You may have to update your app to see it! I just had to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is now available for Echo / Echo Dot as well. The following steps worked for me.

- From the contacts both the parties must enable Drop In.
- Say "Drop In to X" (Not "Call X". Call still makes a call and does not drop in)

Ensure that you have updated the app to the latest version.

Comment: I have the latest version of the app, enabled the drop-in feature for each echo Dot, but there's no option to enable drop in for a contact. Only first and last name can be changed, nothing about drop in shows up.

Comment: Yes they apparently need some quality control in their release process. It seems they sent out a half baked update for a couple of days. The latest Android update fixes it and everything works now.

Comment: Where the hell is contacts?  I realize some us may be slow but I tried to look through the app menu and don't find contacts. (iOS/iPad app).

Comment: You can also drop in on devices, like "Drop in on bedroom echo"

Answer (score 5):

As of late June 2017, Drop In is now available with the following devices:

> - Echo
> - Echo Dot (1st Generation)
> - Echo Dot (2nd Generation)
> - Echo Show

You can also begin a Drop In from the Alexa app to a device (but not vice versa—an Echo cannot Drop In on a phone with the Alexa app). The other answers provide suitable information on how to initiate a Drop In session, so I will not repeat that here. The below information now describes how the situation was previously, as the Echo Show was initially released.

---

Initially (May 2017), "Drop In" was only enabled for the [Echo Show](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J24C0TI), Amazon's new Echo device with a screen.

From [the product documentation](https://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=16713667011):

> Alexa will let you know when someone is calling, and a green light ring will appear on your supported Echo device. You can ask Alexa to answer or ignore the call.
>
> With Echo Show, you’ll also be able to make video calls or use Drop In, a new feature for the special cases when you want to connect instantly with your closest family and friends.

Answer (score 5):

For android the app, at least mine from June 26, 2017, does not have the option to enable Drop In for specific contacts.
However I installed version 2.1.22 of the **iOS** version, which has that option. Probably later versions will also work.
So now I can use Drop In to reach another specific device in my household.

Comment: Yes they apparently need some quality control in their release process. It seems they sent out a half baked update for a couple of days. The latest Android update fixes it and everything works now.

Comment: Stefan, did you do that through the settings menu for each device? That's the only place I see the option, but even though I have it set to on for both my devices, she keeps telling me I need to enable it.

Comment: Lynn, did you also enable Drop In for a contact:

- Open the Alexa app and open the Conversations tab.
- Tap the contact icon in the top right (the icon shaped like a person).
- Select a name from the list of contacts.
- Tap the toggle beside Contact can Drop In anytime.

Comment: Sean, to clarify: since I am not in any of the Alexa's officially supported countries I have to resort to alternatives to the Google play store, just Google searching for the alexa apk, by which I still have not found an Android version that would work as of this writing.

Answer (score 4):

I have not figured out how to do this either, but Drop In is available for devices other than just the Show.

[Amazon Help](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_1-10?ie=UTF8&nodeId=202153130&qid=1498535191&sr=1-10)

> Drop In is an optional feature that helps you to instantly connect, hands free, with your Echo devices and your closest friends and family. You can enable Drop In in the Alexa app and grant permission to yourself and/or contacts from your address book. When you grant permission to yourself, this also applies to your household members. When you grant permission to a contact, this also applies to your contact's household members. You can select which devices have drop in capabilities.
>
> **Compatible Devices**
>
> - Echo Echo Dot
> - (1st Generation)
> - Echo Dot (2nd Generation)
> - Echo Show
> - Alexa app (only for starting Drop In)
>
> Before you can use Drop In, you need to:
>
> - Sign up for Alexa Calling and Messaging
> - Enable Drop In for yourself or a contact
> - Have a contact enable Drop In for you

Comment: While the app does allow you to enable drop-in calling on other devices, the option to enable it for specific contacts doesn't seem to be implemented.  When you tell Alexa to drop in call, it instructs you to enable it for a contact.

Comment: Yes they apparently need some quality control in their release process. It seems they sent out a half baked update for a couple of days. The latest Android update fixes it and everything works now.